# jQuery rotating through list items in a gallery, how to do this with muliple images on a page

Tags: jquery

Hi I have tried the above here http://www.jsfiddle.net/b3Lf5/1/ the trouble is I can not get it to work on my homepage. Also I would like to have this work but for multiple images rotating at different times (would look weird if they rotated at the same time), is this possible. 
Any help would be really appriciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Possibly a picture or some code?

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is to make your code work with objects specified by a class instead of by ID. This way, we can have as many of the slideshows as we want. All you need to do is keep an array containing variables for each slideshow.

Fully working sample with multiple "slideshows" with staggered transition time.

**LIVE DEMO** 
http://jsfiddle.net/b3Lf5/7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery">
    <ul class="gallery-container">
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/ccc" alt=" "></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/aaa" alt=" "></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/888" alt=" "></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/444" alt=" "></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="gallery">
    <ul class="gallery-container">
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/900" alt=" "></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/090" alt=" "></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/009" alt=" "></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/f00" alt=" "></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/0f0" alt=" "></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/250/00f" alt=" "></li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Javascript/jQuery**

```
var shows;
var element;
var length;
var current;
var timeout;
var timers;
var x;

//Begin All Slideshows with classname "gallery"
InitSlideShows('gallery');

function InitSlideShows(className){
    var shows = $('.' + className).length;

    element = new Array(shows);
    length = new Array(shows);
    current = new Array(shows);
    timeout = new Array(shows);
    timers = new Array(shows);
    x=0;

    $('.gallery').each(function(){
        var myIndex=x;
        element[myIndex] = $(this).find('li');
        length[myIndex] = element[myIndex].length;
        current[myIndex] = 0;
        timeout[myIndex] = 1000 * (myIndex+1);
        element[myIndex].slice(1).hide();
        timers[myIndex] = setTimeout(function(){changeSlide(myIndex);}, timeout[x]);
        x++;
    });
}
function changeSlide(ind) {
    element[ind].eq(current[ind]++).fadeOut(300, function(){
        if(current[ind] === length[ind]) current[ind] = 0;      
        element[ind].eq(current[ind]).fadeIn(300);
    });
    timers[ind] = setTimeout(function(){changeSlide(ind);}, timeout[ind]);
}
```

Comment: @Dutchie432 Without trying to sound really stupid and alienante myself from the wealth of knoledge avalible from yourself and other users. This looks like exactly what I want to do, I just cant get it to work.

Comment: Here to help. What's not working, exactly. You should be able to copy and paste my Javascript and HTML right into your page. Do you have a sample page setup that shows the non-functioning code?

Comment: @Dutchie432 I'm working on a testrandom.html which I created and is an exact copy of my site, I copy pasted your html then copy pasted your javascript in a seperate testrandom.js page, I wonder if I'm not linking them together properly? What I get is a long list of boxes, that dont change, instead of two that change randomly. Once I get this working I would like 6 boxes with randomly changing images. I understand this will mean maybe 18 or so images, but I'm sure I have more than enough to choose from. Thanks again

Comment: I saw that result too when I was coding the example. That happens when, for some reason, the `element[myIndex].slice(1).hide();` does not get executed properly. It's really hard for me to troubleshoot without code. can I see your `testrandom.html` page?

Comment: Sure thing, how do I post it. Not enough characters here?

Comment: Can you just send me a URL to look at?

Comment: Im working locally and have not published anything yet, will be doing this tomorrow with some help from a friend. I could email you...or I guess I could message you tomorrow.

Comment: message me here tomorrow. Good luck and happy coding!